# bi-directional motor control using two mosfets

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am trying to understand how a [dual motor controller works](https://grobotronics.com/images/companies/1/datasheets/mr001-004-3_datasheet.pdf). It drives two DC motors with support for running the motors in the opposite direction, as well as stopping them. Looking at the board I spotted two FDS4953 Dual P-Channel mosfets, presumably one for each motor, as well as a transistor. Their [schematic](https://www.sigmaelectronica.net/manuals/FDS4953.pdf) shows that each is comprised of two mosfets. How is the board able to achive this with just two mosfets per motor?

Comment: you linked the driver datasheet instead of the module schematic

Comment: it may be a case of false advertising ... the module can drive two motors unidirectionally or it can drive one motor bidirectionally if you make connections only at the terminal blocks on the module ... off-board connections would be required for bidirectional control of two motors

Comment: @jsoola:: I don't have the circuit schematic; that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @jsotola: Regarding your second comment, an example program on the maker's site https://www.microbot.it/sketches/Dual_DC_Motor_Driver_4A_V3_test_sketch.ino shows simultaneous control of both motors using two potentiometers (this was also useful as i was not sure whether i could drive the motor using a pwm signal).

Comment: _"Looking at the board I spotted two FDS4953 Dual P-Channel mosfets"_ - evidence?

Comment: This is weird. So I looked at the datasheets: (1) Dual DC Motor Driver 4A V3 - MicroRobot
https://grobotronics.com/images/companies/1/datasheets/mr001-004-3_datasheet.pdf

(2) FDS4953 Dual 30V P-Channel Power MOSFET - FairChild
https://www.sigmaelectronica.net/manuals/FDS4953.pdf.  (a) So your board has two dual mosfets which can form one full bridge. (b) One full bridge is required to control one motor's direction. So I think it is mission impossible to control two motors at the same time. Perhaps we can compare and contrast with L298N.

Comment: [A4953: Full-Bridge DMOS PWM Motor Driver](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A4952-3-Datasheet.ashx) https://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-A4953ELJTR-T-IC-PWM-MOTOR-DVR-FULL-8SOIC-A4953-4953-A4953E-4953E-A4953EL-49-/192648475679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the board able to achive this with just two mosfets per motor?

It doesn't. The board actually has two Allegro MicroSystems [A4953](https://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/A4952-3-Datasheet.ashx) DMOS PWM motor drivers. [Here's](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-A4953ELJTR-T-IC-PWM-MOTOR-DVR-FULL-8SOIC-A4953-4953-A4953E-4953E-A4953EL-49-/192648475679) a photo of the IC:-

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this is clearly supported by the single pair of supply inputs and the truth table given which is that of a full bridge per motor.

Comment: Thank you very mush! The picture of the board was not very clear and i could only make out the "4953" part. This coincidentally also matched the  "FDS4953" mosfets but the one you found looks like the right one.

Answer (score 1):

> *How is the board able to achive this with just two mosfets per motor?*

And

> *Looking at the board I spotted two FDS4953 Dual P-Channel mosfets*

Right on the front page is the hint to how it does this: -

> **The Dual DC Motor Driver 4A V3 allows to indipendently drive two DC
> motors, controlling both velocity and direction. The minimum supply
> voltage allowed is 7V, so you can use also two-cell LiPo batteries
> (7.4V) that grant small dimensions and low weight characteristics.**

<sub>Wrong voltage corrected below</sub>

Ignoring the spelling (I'm certainly no expert), it suggests using two 3.7 volt batteries in series and this means that one motor wire can terminate to the battery midpoint. This means that one MOSFET can pull the remaining motor wire up to 7.4 volts (applying +3.7 volts to get forward motion) whilst the other MOSFET can pull it down to 0 volts (applying -3.7 volts to get reverse direction): -

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think the reference to the two cell 7.4 volts means two 3.7 LiPo cells connected in series to drive the board, rather than center tapping two 7.4 batteries. Also the board's input power terminal provides only two screw inputs, rather than three.

Comment: @DionysisSpinellis Yes I got the voltage stated incorrectly but my point is still valid. At the series junction of the two batteries is where one wire on the motor makes a connection. The other connection on the motor connects to the half bridge output hence, the motor can be driven forwards, backwards or anywhere in between. Do you follow?

Comment: I don't follow. I think something goes wrong somewhere.

Comment: @tlfong01 does the added picture help?

Comment: @Andy aka, Many thanks for your clarification. (1) I said I didn't follow you because (a) I agree your center tapping two batteries trick is innovative, and might work, but I have never seen such a trick, so I said I didn't follow because I am not sure if I understand your description of the circuit. (b) You picture confirms my understanding, so I could now follow your reasoning. But I am new to power MOSFET, so I need to to think hard to convenience me this trick works. I will report back later, might take some time. :)

Comment: Think of the motor as a loudspeaker and the two MOSFETs as a [push pull output stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3u2E.png) in an audio power amplifier. Does that help?

Comment: Ha, your first picture clarifies, but second picture confuses me again. You remind me that long time ago, I used NPN BJT and PNP BJT to form a complimentary pair to make a power amp, to push pull a loudspeaker. I vaguely remember that using one BJT needs to work in B region/mode/type, and if two BJTs working together, would work in A or C mode (I forgot). Nowadays everybody is using digital D type pwr amp. So I am hopeless out of day, but I don't worry, because I can just buy a cheap D-type module, more HiFi, very small size, no heat sink, no decoupling cap, direct drive speaker / to cont ...

Comment: That'll be "complementary" and not "complimentary" @tlfong01

Comment: Your complementary N-type P-type MOSFET does not seem to meet the OP's requirement of only two same type MOSFETs to control direction of motor. But your push pull power amp ***with two diodes*** and the earlier two battery solution inspires me something. Let me go to the drawing board to think aloud my new design. See you later. PS - Your spelling lesson is indeed a compliment. Cheers.

Comment: They are not MOSFETs and that picture was a "think of it as..." demonstration and not an equivalent to what the OP stated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111852/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-andy-aka).

Comment: @tlfong01 I thinks it's best that you formulate a question and formally raise it rather than use a chat room.